# What is the Maximum number of seats in a Congress you can get?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I am wondering how to resolve this kind of question.

My wild guess is to imagine 10 parties get 4.99% of the votes (each), so the other two parties can each have 25% votes and get 50 seats each.

Congress has 100 seats. Only parties with strictly more than 5% of votes qualify to get seats. There are 12 parties in total. Seats are distributed to the parties that qualified, proportionally to votes. Votes are strictly for 1 party (no voting for multiple parties or no party).

What is the maximum seats that a party with 25% of the votes can get?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My wild guess is imagine 10 parties get 4.99% votes, so the other two parties can each have 25% votes and get 50 seats each. But I hope I can analyse the question in a more mathematical way

Comment: What about $19$ parties each getting $4$% of the votes, and a $20$-th party, that gets $24$% of the votes.  If I am interpreting your constraints correctly, wouldn't the $20$-th party get all $100$ seats?

Comment: We only have 12 parties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions in the problem statement itself are a little unmathematical, so if you want to be mathematical the first thing to do is to come up with a better way to describe this system of representation.

There are $N$ votes in total and each party $n$ gets $v_n$ votes.
Let $p_n = v_n/N$ be that party's share of the total vote.

Let $p$ be the some of $p_n$ over all parties that qualified. That is, $p$ is the  total relative portion of the total vote received by all qualifying parties.
Therefore $p$ is a rational number in the interval $[0,1].$ (Further conditions will provide a greater minimum, but we're just defining terms here.)

For example, if two parties get exactly $3\%$ each and all other parties get at least $6\%,$ then $p = 0.94.$

Now for each qualifying party $n$ we let $q_n = p_n / p.$
This is the portion of the total qualifying vote earned by party $n.$

And somehow this number $q_n$ translates to a number of representatives $r_n.$

The question does not specify how to handle cases where $q_n$ is not an exact multiple of $1/100.$ We can imagine that in an actual voting system like this there might not be a direct mapping from $q_n$ to $r_n.$ The number of seats $r_n$ might depend on exactly how the qualifying vote was distributed among the other parties as well as on $q_n.$
This makes it a little difficult to proceed in a completely mathematical way.

The fact that the number of seats $r_n$ is always an integer also makes some calculus-based methods not work very well.

But let's first see what we can say about $q_n.$

Without loss of generality (WLOG), because we can number the parties any way we like without changing the outcome, suppose party $1$ gets exactly $25\%$ of the total vote, that is, $p_1 = 0.25.$
Then $q_1 = 0.25/p.$
We maximize $q_1$ by minimizing $p.$

According to the problem statement, "Only parties with strictly more than $5\%$ of votes qualify to get seats."
In mathematical terms, unless $p_n > 0.05$ (**strictly** more than $5\%$), party $n$ does not qualify.
So the minimum $p$ occurs when a $k$ parties are disqualified, maximizing $k$, and each of those parties receives exactly $p_n = 0.05$ of the vote.

We see that $k=10$ is possible but $k=11$ is not. So let $k = 10$, WLOG let the only two qualifying parties be parties $1$ and $2,$ and let $p_3 = \cdots = p_12 = 0.05.$
Then $p = 0.5.$ It is not possible for any of the $p_n$ for parties $3$ through $12$ to be any greater (otherwise the party would qualify), and if any is less than $0.05$ then $p > 0.5,$ so this is the minimum $p$.

Therefore the maximum $q_1$ is $0.25 / 0.5 = 0.5.$
Since this is an exact multiple of $1/100$, giving each qualifying party $50$ seats is exactly proportional to the vote and any other arrangement is not,
so presumably the parties get $50$ seats each.

If $k = 10$ but $p < 0.5$ then party $2$ has more votes than party $1,$ so presumably (since only those two parties are seated) party $1$ cannot get more seats than party $2$ and can have at most $50$ seats.

If $k < 10$ then $p \leq 0.45.$ In that case $q_1 \leq 0.25/0.55 \approx 0.4545.$
That is, party $1$ has less than $46\%$ of the qualifying vote, and to have even $45\%$ there must be only three qualifying parties.
Again, we don't have an exact set of rules for how the votes translate into integer numbers of seats in such cases; there must be some kind of rounding effect,
but it's hard to imagine a rounding effect that will transfer five seats from the other two parties to party $1.$

I've given more detail than I possibly should have. A better "mathematical" explanation might have said some of these conclusions were "obvious" without going into such detail, because you should be able to work out the details easily enough.